# Possible to have Visual Studio TODO comments in aspx/ascx files appear in task list?

Tags: visual-studio, comments

We develop asp.net webforms using visual studio 2008.  For multilingual support, we translate all our text.  However, when designing, we usually just enter the english text and come back to translation later (it interrupts flow of work otherwise).

I've added a "ToTranslate" tag in the options.  Adding `//ToTranslate: something` in C# code correctly adds the entry to the Task List.  I haven't however figured out how to do the same for aspx and ascx files (where most of our user text lives).

Inserting `<%-- //ToTranslate: something --%>` or `<%-- ToTranslate: something --%>` doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: From a non-technical point of view, you could preface all untranslated text with a !bang so wherever you see text that starts with it, you know you need to translate it.  Or you could use a ¦special §ascii ¨character that would enable you to search through the entire codebase for them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems to me that it works fine if you put the delimiters <% and %> on a line by themselves. What I did was this: go to Tools menu and click on Options, then under Environment -> Task List add a new ToTranslate token. Click OK to accept the change. Back on the ASPX page I added the comments on a line by themselves and the code delimiters on lines by themselves.

Comment: Yup, the double dash was what was keeping it from working.  They don't even need their own line <% //ToTranslate: xxx %>

Comment: Note that the two forward slashes are also required for it to work (e.g. `<% TODO %>` won't work).

Answer (score 8):

FYI if you want to do this in a **.Net MVC3 razor cshtml file** the syntax this:

```
@{
//TODO: Move this inline <style> css to a file
}
```

Take note: that you need to put the trailing } bracket on a new line as otherwise it will be included in the // comment. You could do it using /**/ like below and keep it all on one line but it's more typing, and a bit harder to read. My take is, if it annoys you the comment takes up 3 lines in your file, all the more motivation to fix the issue and remove it completely :)

```
@{/*TODO: Move this inline <style> css to a file*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the <% %> on lines by themselves. This example shows what works and what does not:

```
<%//ToTranslate will work%>
<%/*ToTranslate will work*/%>
<!--ToTranslate won't work-->
<!--
ToTranslate won't work
-->
```

It may be due to the fact that what's differentiating between an HTML comment and some form of aspx comment is getting messed up by the -- because that's part of an html comment?

[image: comments in aspx]