# Visual studio TODO comment in xml file to task list

Tags: xml, visual-studio, todo

Is it possible to put TODO comments from xml files included in project to Task list in Visual Studio 2013?

We are using a lot of XML files and it would be handy to use TODO, HACK or other keywords for Task list.

Comment: This appears to be the same problem I am having with a `web.config` file and my TODO's there not appearing in Tasks list. Resharper was the answer for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper has a [To-do Explorer window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Windows__To-do_Explorer.html) which will pick up any ToDos in your XML files. You can configure it to report 'HACK' or any other pattern in the Resharper > Options > Tools > To-do Explorer. The pattern is a Reg-Ex so for example the Todo pattern is:

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO)(\W|$)(.*)
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude files this way too? Say for example, I dont want any TODO lines to show up from external javascript libraries?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no built-in tool to view comments from XML files in Task list window of Visual Studio 2013.

But there are several 3-d party tools. For example, **VS10x Comments Extender**, which has a shareware version to download. I've never tried such tools myself but you can take a look at description on [Visual studio gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/17c68951-7743-40bd-ad35-608706f54a92).

There's also [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923333/possible-to-have-visual-studio-todo-comments-in-aspx-ascx-files-appear-in-task-l) about aspx/ascx and cshtml files.